# jQuery Facebox: Sends empty input field value

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, facebox

I have facebox plugin to my jQuery, to make lightbox for me.
I made a link that you click on and then a friend request form comes up in it.

The form makes an ajaxcall when click on "Send request", but the 2 fields dont send anything of what you have written in it, it just sends empty value.

But if its not inside the facebox lightbox then it works and sends the values in the ajax call.

So something in the facebox.js is preventing the fields and send them empty values.

How can i solve this?

Here's facebox.js:

```
    (function($) {
  $.facebox = function(data, klass) {
    $.facebox.loading()

    if (data.ajax) fillFaceboxFromAjax(data.ajax)
    else if (data.image) fillFaceboxFromImage(data.image)
    else if (data.div) fillFaceboxFromHref(data.div)
    else if ($.isFunction(data)) data.call($)
    else $.facebox.reveal(data, klass)
  }

  /*
   * Public, $.facebox methods
   */

  $.extend($.facebox, {
    settings: {
      opacity      : 0,
      overlay      : true,
      loadingImage : 'images/loading.gif',
      closeImage   : 'images/closelabel.png',
      imageTypes   : [ 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif' ],
      faceboxHtml  : '\
    <div id="facebox" style="display:none;"> \
      <div class="popup"> \
        <table> \
          <tbody> \
            <tr> \
              <td class="tl"/><td class="b"/><td class="tr"/> \
            </tr> \
            <tr> \
              <td class="b"/> \
              <td class="body"> \
                <div class="content"> \
                </div> \
                <div class="footer"> \
                  <a href="#" class="close"> \
                    <img src="/facebox/closelabel.gif" title="close" class="close_image" /> \
                  </a> \
                </div> \
              </td> \
              <td class="b"/> \
            </tr> \
            <tr> \
              <td class="bl"/><td class="b"/><td class="br"/> \
            </tr> \
          </tbody> \
        </table> \
      </div> \
    </div>'
    },

    loading: function() {
      init()
      if ($('#facebox .loading').length == 1) return true
      showOverlay()

      $('#facebox .content').empty()
      $('#facebox .body').children().hide().end().
        append('<div class="loading"><img src="'+$.facebox.settings.loadingImage+'"/></div>')

      $('#facebox').css({
        top:    getPageScroll()[1] + (getPageHeight() / 10),
        left:   385.5
      }).show()

      $(document).bind('keydown.facebox', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) $.facebox.close()
        return true
      })
      $(document).trigger('loading.facebox')
    },

    reveal: function(data, klass) {
      $(document).trigger('beforeReveal.facebox')
      if (klass) $('#facebox .content').addClass(klass)
      $('#facebox .content').append(data)
      $('#facebox .loading').remove()
      $('#facebox .body').children().fadeIn('normal')
      $('#facebox').css('left', $(window).width() / 2 - ($('#facebox table').width() / 2))
      $(document).trigger('reveal.facebox').trigger('afterReveal.facebox')
    },

    close: function() {
      $(document).trigger('close.facebox')
      return false
    }
  })

  /*
   * Public, $.fn methods
   */

  $.fn.facebox = function(settings) {
    init(settings)

    function clickHandler() {
      $.facebox.loading(true)

      // support for rel="facebox.inline_popup" syntax, to add a class
      // also supports deprecated "facebox[.inline_popup]" syntax
      var klass = this.rel.match(/facebox\[?\.(\w+)\]?/)
      if (klass) klass = klass[1]

      fillFaceboxFromHref(this.href, klass)
      return false
    }

    return this.click(clickHandler)
  }

  /*
   * Private methods
   */

  // called one time to setup facebox on this page
  function init(settings) {
    if ($.facebox.settings.inited) return true
    else $.facebox.settings.inited = true

    $(document).trigger('init.facebox')
    makeCompatible()

    var imageTypes = $.facebox.settings.imageTypes.join('|')
    $.facebox.settings.imageTypesRegexp = new RegExp('\.' + imageTypes + '$', 'i')

    if (settings) $.extend($.facebox.settings, settings)
    $('body').append($.facebox.settings.faceboxHtml)

    var preload = [ new Image(), new Image() ]
    preload[0].src = $.facebox.settings.closeImage
    preload[1].src = $.facebox.settings.loadingImage

    $('#facebox').find('.b:first, .bl, .br, .tl, .tr').each(function() {
      preload.push(new Image())
      preload.slice(-1).src = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/url\((.+)\)/, '$1')
    })

    $('#facebox .close').click($.facebox.close)
    $('#facebox .close_image').attr('src', $.facebox.settings.closeImage)
  }

  // getPageScroll() by quirksmode.com
  function getPageScroll() {
    var xScroll, yScroll;
    if (self.pageYOffset) {
      yScroll = self.pageYOffset;
      xScroll = self.pageXOffset;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {     // Explorer 6 Strict
      yScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      xScroll = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    } else if (document.body) {// all other Explorers
      yScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
      xScroll = document.body.scrollLeft;   
    }
    return new Array(xScroll,yScroll) 
  }

  // Adapted from getPageSize() by quirksmode.com
  function getPageHeight() {
    var windowHeight
    if (self.innerHeight) { // all except Explorer
      windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) { // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
      windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if (document.body) { // other Explorers
      windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    }   
    return windowHeight
  }

  // Backwards compatibility
  function makeCompatible() {
    var $s = $.facebox.settings

    $s.loadingImage = $s.loading_image || $s.loadingImage
    $s.closeImage = $s.close_image || $s.closeImage
    $s.imageTypes = $s.image_types || $s.imageTypes
    $s.faceboxHtml = $s.facebox_html || $s.faceboxHtml
  }

  // Figures out what you want to display and displays it
  // formats are:
  //     div: #id
  //   image: blah.extension
  //    ajax: anything else
  function fillFaceboxFromHref(href, klass) {
    // div
    if (href.match(/#/)) {
      var url    = window.location.href.split('#')[0]
      var target = href.replace(url,'')
      $.facebox.reveal($(target).clone().show(), klass)

    // image
    } else if (href.match($.facebox.settings.imageTypesRegexp)) {
      fillFaceboxFromImage(href, klass)
    // ajax
    } else {
      fillFaceboxFromAjax(href, klass)
    }
  }

  function fillFaceboxFromImage(href, klass) {
    var image = new Image()
    image.onload = function() {
      $.facebox.reveal('<div class="image"><img src="' + image.src + '" /></div>', klass)
    }
    image.src = href
  }

  function fillFaceboxFromAjax(href, klass) {
    $.get(href, function(data) { $.facebox.reveal(data, klass) })
  }

  function skipOverlay() {
    return $.facebox.settings.overlay == false || $.facebox.settings.opacity === null 
  }

  function showOverlay() {
    if (skipOverlay()) return

    if ($('facebox_overlay').length == 0) 
      $("body").append('<div id="facebox_overlay" class="facebox_hide"></div>')

    $('#facebox_overlay').hide().addClass("facebox_overlayBG")
      .css('opacity', $.facebox.settings.opacity)
      .click(function() { $(document).trigger('close.facebox') })
      .fadeIn(200)
    return false
  }

  function hideOverlay() {
    if (skipOverlay()) return

    $('#facebox_overlay').fadeOut(200, function(){
      $("#facebox_overlay").removeClass("facebox_overlayBG")
      $("#facebox_overlay").addClass("facebox_hide") 
      $("#facebox_overlay").remove()
    })

    return false
  }

  /*
   * Bindings
   */

  $(document).bind('close.facebox', function() {
    $(document).unbind('keydown.facebox')
    $('#facebox').fadeOut(function() {
      $('#facebox .content').removeClass().addClass('content')
      hideOverlay()
      $('#facebox .loading').remove()
    })
  })

})(jQuery);
```

Here's my form even though i doubt anything is wrong here as it works outside the box:

```
        <div id="addFriend" style="display: none;">
                <div style="float:right; font-size: 14px;">Add <strong><?php echo $showU["full_name"]; ?></strong> as friend </div>
                <div class="clearfloat"></div>

<form id="FriendRequest" action="javascript:DoFriendRequest(<?php echo $v["id"]; ?>, <? echo $showU["id"]; ?>)" method="post">

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
  $("label").inFieldLabels();
});
    </script> 
                <table align="center" width="auto" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" style="margin: auto;">
                <tr>
                <td style="padding: 10px;" align="center">
                Comment: </td><td>
                <span class="field">

                <input name="commentFriend" type="text" id="commentFriend" style="height: auto;"value="" size="22"> 
                </span>
                </td></tr><tr>
                <td style="padding: 10px;"  align="center">
                Message:
                </td><td> 
                <span class="field">

                <input name="messageFriend" type="text" id="messageFriend" value="" size="22">
                </span>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="margin: auto; text-align: center;">
                <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Send request">
                </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="margin: auto; text-align: center;">
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </form>

                <div style="margin: auto; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;" id="insert_svar"></div>
    </div>
```

DoFriendRequest()

```
function DoFriendRequest(BuID, uID){
  $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  var wrapperId = '#insert_svar';
    $.ajax({ 
       type: "POST",
       url: "misc/AddFriendRequest.php",
    data: {
    mode: 'ajax',
    BuID : BuID,
    uID : uID, 
    message : $('#messageFriend').val(),
    comment : $('#commentFriend').val() 
    },
       success: function(msg){
       $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
     $(wrapperId).prepend(msg);
     $('#FriendRequest').fadeOut('slow'); 
     $('#message').val("");
     $('#comment').val("");
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: Could you share the whole markup? I can't help you out if I don't have the whole source code. Sorry I was suppose to just leave a comment on your question but I don't have enough reputation to do so. I'll update this answer when I come up with one. As a temporary answer to your question, you might want to check this out. It might help - http://www.caiapps.com/stick-on-facebox/

Comment: Do you have this on a page somewhere so you can provide a link? That would be easier to test than rebuilding your page to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
$.facebox.reveal($(target).clone().show(), klass)
```

It's cloning your elements, specifically `id="messageFriend"` and `id="commentFriend"` which is causing issues since they're *supposed* to be unique.  The [`#ID` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) is finding the *original* elements which are still empty (the cloned ones have the values you're after).

To resolve this, 
I would remove the `id` attributes and find them by `name` instead...and then only find the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) ones, which would be the currently open facebox, like this:

```
function DoFriendRequest(BuID, uID){
  $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  var wrapperId = '#insert_svar';
  $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "misc/AddFriendRequest.php",
    data: {
      mode: 'ajax',
      BuID : BuID,
      uID : uID, 
      message : $('input[name=messageFriend]:visible').val(),
      comment : $('input[name=commentFriend]:visible').val() 
    },
    success: function(msg){
      $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
      $(wrapperId).prepend(msg);
      $('#FriendRequest').fadeOut('slow'); 
      $('#message, #comment').val("");
    }
  });
}
```

[You can try the updated version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/nQj6G/3/), take a look at the console to see it is indeed submitting the values now.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("target:last").serialize()
```